# Using service to unminimize app instead of new intent

Tags: android

I have the following code:

```
private void chathead_click(){
        if(MainActivity.active){
            //MyDialog.myDialog.finish();
        }else{
            Intent it = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(it);
        }

    }
```

When I click my service icon, it open my app main intent as executed in the above statement:

```
Intent it = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(it);
```

I need to do in code the **same action** as clicking the android button which shows all the applications, and clicking my application to access it back. When I create a new intent, I lose the values I put in my EditTextViews.

Answer (score 0):

Provides intent by static method in the Activity you want to open.
Check android best practices on google!

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static Intent mIntent;

public static Intent newIntent(Context context, boolean shouldCreateNewIntent) {
    if (null == mIntent || shouldCreateNewIntent) {
        mIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    }
    return mIntent;
}
}
```

Just call newIntent method from any Activity

```
    startActivity(MainActivity.newIntent(this, false));
```

Comment: I think you missunderstand my question, I don't want to create a new intent, my code works, I just want to unminimize/untray my app.